# Iptable forward interfaces for gateway machine

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, routing

I have two Ethernet interface being configured to use as system gateway
ex:

- eth1: 10.10.1.0
- eth2: 10.10.2.0

I want to forward all the packets which are coming to the 10.10.2.0 gateway contacting 10.10.1.x via eth1 (10.10.1.0), and the reverse as packets coming to 10.10.1.x, contacting 10.10.2.0 machines via eth2.

How can I write `iptables` rules for this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Do you have existing `iptables` rules? Add the output of `iptables -L -vn` to your question.

Answer (score 2):

For a generic router, try the following as a script

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -d 10.10.2.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -d 10.10.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Comment: You often also need `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE` and same with eth2.